# Solve this equation to the nearest degree, giving all solutions between 0 and 360 degrees

Tags: geometry

$\sin(θ-50^\circ)= -0.9$

I know you first have to find the reference angle by finding the inverse function of sine, which gives $-64^\circ$ but then I'm not sure what to do next?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Think about how many angles $\alpha$ have $\sin\alpha=64°$...draw a picture!